# React Paypal Buttons intent

Tags: javascript, reactjs, laravel, paypal, payment

I am using using react-paypal-button-v2 in my react app! i want to hold payment while my order is completed! i.e first complete the `db transaction` after that go fo paypal payment!
if i use paypal intent as `authorize` then it hold paymant but how later on it will pay after db transactio` in my react component!

here is my code but this method didn't work for me

```
onApprove(data, actions)
 {
   actions.order.capture();
 }

 <PayPalButton
    options={paypalOptions}
    amount="1.00"
    onApprove={this.onApprove}
 />
```

Answer (score 0):

When intent=authorize is used for an order, capturing the order will result in an authorization Payment object.

To capture that authorization Payment object, use the following API call: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments/v2/#authorizations_capture